# Numpy eig/eigh high memory usage

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Let me start with a disclaimer that I am not as experienced in Python as one might want to be, so it could be that this is being caused by something I had caused myself.

Disclaimer aside, I've noticed some strange behavior in terms of the memory usage in NumPy. Specifically, when performing eigenvalue decompositions (I request both eigenvalues and eigenvectors) the memory usage is significantly larger than expected. This becomes a problem when the matrix size is such that we can not afford to store several copies.

A typical LAPACK implementation (which NumPy calls -- at some point) will compute the eigenvectors in place, thus the memory requirement will be roughly 8N^2+O(N) -- with the 8 coming from the double precision floating point data type used in my case. Thus, with NumPy being supposedly relatively efficient one would expect something similar. Admittedly, we know to expect twice as much, as NumPy will keep the original matrix, so it must at some point make at least a single copy.

Interestingly, this is most definitely not what is observed. As an example, we can track the memory usage, as reported by */proc/<pid>/status*, of the following code (using Python 3.9.7, NumPy 1.26.2, SciPy 1.11.3):

```
    import numpy
    import time
    import scipy
    
    N=10000
    A=numpy.random.randn(N, N)
    B=2**-0.5 * (A+A.T)
    del A
    
    # This will create an easy to identify structure on the graph
    time.sleep(1)
    C=numpy.random.randn(N, N)
    del C
    time.sleep(1)
    
    evals,evecs = numpy.linalg.eigh(B)
    
    # This will create an easy to identify structure on the graph
    time.sleep(1)
    C=numpy.random.randn(N, N)
    del C
    time.sleep(1)
```

For reference, the following tests were performed on a node with 2x AMD EPYC 7702 with OMP_NUM_THREADS=16 running Debian bullseye (Linux 5.10.0-26-amd64), though I don't expect this to be relevant to anything other than the runtime in the plots, which is irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Looking at the time between the two dashed vertical lines, where the `numpy.linalg.eigh` call takes place, we observe higher memory usage than expected.
[image: numpy.linalg.eigh memory use] The horizontal lines represent the expected size of a matrix of our chosen size. We see that, on top of the single copy we expect, we get two more copies roughly half-way through the calculation. Furthermore, at the very end there appears to be another copy being created, presumably as something is being copied as opposed to moved. In short, we've gone from 2 times the size to 5 times. So my question is, why does this happen and how, if possible, can it be resolved? Ideally I would also avoid having the original copy but as far as I understand this was considered at some point but not implemented in NumPy, so I assume that is not possible at the moment.

Curiously, replacing `numpy.linalg.eigh` with `numpy.linalg.eig`, we see even worse performance at the end (not only in time, which is expected, but also in the memory use). [image: numpy.linalg.eig memory use]
At first we see the same behavior, though half-way through we only get one more copy this time around, however at the very end we appear to incur a significantly greater overhead with an additional 4 temporary copies (in terms of the memory use, whether or not that is the result of 4 copies I do not know) being created.

I would assume this is some sort of bug in the implementation of NumPy, at the very least that peak at the very end? Particularly in light of what happens if we try a different implementation, which also uses the LAPACK backend.

We can swap to SciPy (`scipy.linalg.eigh`), which offers similar functions (though slightly worse performance it seems), which do not suffer from the same peak in memory use at the very end, though we still have 3 copies, which is still not ideal.
[image: scipy.linalg.eigh memory use]

SciPy also allows us to use the option `overwrite_a=True`, which should, according to the documentation, overwrite the matrix. As far as I understand this should then lead to the expected memory behavior in line with what one would observe in C/C++/Fortran, but in practice it does nothing. [image: scipy.linalg.eigh with overwrite_a=True memory use]
Indeed, we see roughly identical behavior as without this setting, both in terms of time and space.

**TL;DR**

How to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix in Python with minimal memory use, both NumPy and SciPy appear to have quite some overhead with NumPy being significantly worse?

**EDIT 1**

Potentially relevant links so far:

1. [How to predict memory requirement for np.linalg.inv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70746660/how-to-predict-memory-requirement-for-np-linalg-inv)  -  discusses a similar issue for the inverse, however only for the 3x memory usage in the majority of the algorithm. Does not discuss the peak at the very end.
2. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14024  -  seems to only mention a 2x memory usage due to the copy, that feature request has not been implemented (so it seems), but that only explains a small part of the observed memory usage and I don't think is particularly relevant. They also mention `overwrite_a` not doing anything for the memory usage in SciPy, which seems to have remained true.

Comment: Hi,
is using python an absolute necessity here, or is this just some kind of benchmarking/prototyping phase?

Comment: Oh no, I can and will rewrite the code in C++ and for me this will no longer be an issue. However, I am curious in a more general sense, particularly about that peak at the very end. I'm not familiar enough with how Python interfaces with C++ to know where this happens in their source, at least not without spending a considerable amount of time. Though of course, for future use, I wonder if there is a way to do this in Python with as little overhead as possible.

Comment: You could argue that this might be down to a multitude of things.
Maybe, as you pointed out, this is a Py-C++ interface issue.
Python does memory handling on a chunk of private heap, and you could argue that stack is faster for some use cases, thus causing greater loads.

Also, have you tried running your benchmark code without `time.sleep()`?

Comment: Perhaps, and lets say that something like that would explain the x3 (though I remain skeptical - really US, with a K?). Nevertheless, there is a clear difference between NumPy and SciPy, so at the very least that peak at the end is curious (and I would guess a bug of some sort). Sure, without `time.sleep()` it does the same, it was really there just to make sure I could track things accurately, but it actually seems to have been unnecessary.

Comment: Here is the code which implements eigh: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4ca8204c5c13b3a5c9482772813e67184f3f47c8/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.cpp#L1489 Looking at it, I can see a few things that are allocating memory. init_linearize_matrix() allocates memory to do a C/Fortran data order conversion. (I think.) init_evd() allocates memory for both a matrix and a scratch area. It seems like it allocates memory for linearizing even if the matrix is already in the correct order? Seems weird.

Comment: Keep in mind that these functions have been around for a long time.  What might have been easy, or straight forward 20 years ago, might  not be optimal now when memory and problems are much larger.  You can examine the repository to see the history of changes.  Has any one tried to refine the memory use?